# VMware very slow

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, vmware

I got **VMware** on my laptop, I installed **Ubuntu** and **Windows 8** unto it, but it runs *really* slowly. I increased the RAM for both OS but still no improvements.

How can I make it start-up faster and run smoother?

- OS: Widows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- RAM: 4 GB
- HDD: 500GB

[image: Windows config][image: Ubuntu Config]

Comment: how about posting your basic data like: CPU, RAM, RAM dedicated to VMs, are you using SSD/HDD, specifics of your VM-setup and your Laptop would greatly help to narrow down the cause ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you have to specify the virtualization engine in Hardware -> 'Processor' and enable VT technologies in Bios